# How to get code completion in React's LAZY component in Vscode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am getting code completions for this component when I import it not as a lazy component .

```
const AceEditor = React.lazy(() => import('react-ace'));
```

When I import it like shown above , I don't get any intellisense or code completion for any of the props of the component when I am using it later within the `Suspense` component.

How do I fix this ?